# Android - get GPS coordinates and location

Tags: java, android, json, gps

I try to develop an application to track the GPS data from User. If I have the longitude and latitude i want to convert these in a location. (That is working with static data as you can see in my code)

My problem is to get the variables from longitude and latitude into the JSON-request - geocode/json?latlng=42.774955,18.955061",

At the end there should stay "...geocode/json?latlng"+lat+","+lng+...

Every time I try this I get NULL values. Please help me.

```
public class MatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private TextView textView;
private TextView textViewCity;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private double lat;
private double lng;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_location);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Coordinates);
    textViewCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCity);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new myLocationlistener();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Location location = new Location("");
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            lat = location.getLatitude();

            Log.e("Latitude", String.valueOf(lat));
            Log.e("Longitude", String.valueOf(lng));

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=42.774955,18.955061", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                        textViewCity.setText(address);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });

}

private class myLocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null){
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `Location` object and using it's coordinates instead of using the `lat` and `lng` values set in the `onLocationChanged(...)` callback.

Comment: Okay, but I already created a new Location object `Location location = new Location("");` @Titus

Comment: Yes and that is the problem, you should use the values that are set when the location is changed.

Comment: But this is not working if I do it in that way `lng = myLocationlistener(new myLocationlistener(lng));`

Comment: If the location changes, the `lng` and `lat` value will be set by the `onLocationChanged(...)` method. In the `onClick(...)` you don't need to set this values, you only need to check if they were already set.

Comment: But i need the longitude and latitude for the JSON request to get the actual location.

Comment: Yes, I know, take a look to see how `LocationListener` works and I think you'll understand what I'm trying to say. Basically the instance variables `lat` and `lng` are set when the location is changed.

Comment: Now it´s working, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `null` values for your `Location` object because you are *initializing an object every time the `Button` is clicked*, and getting the values of that object. When a `Location` object is created, it has no properties, unless you set them using `location.setLatitude()` or `location.setLongitude()`. To solve your problem, just remove the lines:

```
Location location = new Location("");
lng = location.getLongitude();
lat = location.getLatitude();
```

When you get the coordinates to log them, you will not get a `null` value since you are setting them in your `onLocationChanged()` listener. You should also add an initial check in `onCreate()` to check for the location. 
After doing this, you should be able to write `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lng"` for the `String` you are passing to you `JSONObjectRequest`.

Comment: Thanks you very much, now it´s working! :) didn't recognize that I get the values in the onLocationChanged() method!

Comment: Great, glad I helped!